# How to indent code in \begin{verbatim}

Tags: verbatim

I have code. I used `\begin{verbatim} \end{verbatim}`. My code contains indentation to organize the code. But the `verbatim` does not add spaces. When I try to add vertical spaces using `\quad`, the  command `\quad` appears as it is. How can I indent my code inside `verbatim`?

Comment: Add spaces (blank characters)

Comment: most likely you have tabs which by default don't work, convert them to spaces or the `verbatim` package has an option to handle tab

Comment: Try with `\usepackage{fancyvrb}` an the `Verbatim` environment (note the upper case initial).

Answer (score 12):

You can use `fancyvrb` (this is the [CTAN repository](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb)); its `Verbatim` environment respects tabs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}
1234567890
	12345678901234567890
		1234567890
	12345678901234567890
1234567890
\end{Verbatim}

\begin{Verbatim}[tabsize=4]
1234567890
	12345678901234567890
		1234567890
	12345678901234567890
1234567890
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

The default value of `tabsize` is 8; you can set it once for all with `\fvset{tabsize=4}` (or whatever value you want) in the document preamble.

**Technical note** Pasting on the site changes tabs to spaces. The second and fourth lines have one tab, the third line has two.

[image]

Comment: It works nicely for me. It doesn't like in-line comments though. For example, `\begin{Verbatim}[tabsize=4]  % comment` throws an error that disappears when the comment is on a new line.

Comment: @XavierStuvw It's not possible; anything after `\begin{Verbatim}` is typeset verbatim, including comments; for implementation reasons, tokens after the options are discarded (with error)

Comment: Make sure the V is capital by the way folks.

Answer (score 4):

The verbatim environment ignores tabs but not white space characters. If your code is just a short snippet and you want to avoid excess packages you could just use the space bar. It's perhaps less elegant but since it will be displayed in a monospace typeface it's not all that bad in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways with the `verbatimbox` package.  The first way will pagebreak, but adds space above/below the environment.  The second way does not page break, but is flexibly manipulated in the manner of a LaTeX box (i.e., one can apply `\centering`, etc. to the box or, as here, frame it)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{verbnobox}[\small\slshape\hspace{1in}]
Lorem ipsum
do\or $it amet%,
consectetuer
\end{verbnobox}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{verbbox}[\small\slshape]
Lorem ipsum
do\or $it amet%,
consectetuer
\end{verbbox}
\noindent\hspace{1in}\fbox{\theverbbox}

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The package [moreverb](https://ctan.org/pkg/moreverb?lang=en) also solves that issue and provides lines numbering.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Could you add a complete example to check your solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `verbatim` started to respect indentation only after I switched all tab symbols to equivalent amounts of whitespaces.
Initial code and output in latex(note that tabs are designated as `\t` here):

```
\begin{verbatim}
\t  for i in range(len(W)): 
\t  \t  print(f'W_{i+1}(s) = {W[i]}')
\end{verbatim}
```

[image]:

After said changes:

```
\begin{verbatim}
    for i in range(len(W)): 
        print(f'W_{i+1}(s) = {W[i]}')
\end{verbatim}
```

[image]