# Numbering correctly indented Verbatim code blocks

Tags: numbering, indentation, labels, verbatim, code

I have been looking through the tex.stackechange community answers and questions and I've not managed to find an answer to my problem. I want to be able to write blocks of code in a verbatim-like environment in LaTeX and have them also numbered in a way reminiscent of how equations are numbered but with a different label.

Thanks to the question [How to indent code in \begin{verbatim}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351961/how-to-indent-code-in-beginverbatim) and the documentation of the [fancyvrb package](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.pdf) 
I have so far the following in my tex file:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[obeytabs,frame=single,rulecolor=\color{red}]
for state in basis_with_fixed_M:
  if state is not in any class yet:
    create new class
    add state to the class
    state' = T(state)
    multiplicity = 1
    while state' != state:
      add state' to the class
      multiplicity++
      state' = T(state')
    representative = min(class)
\end{Verbatim}
```

which looks as I want
[image: block of code correctly indented] 
apart from that I am not able to correctly create a way to number this block, even after studying the great answer Steven B. Segletes in the question [How can I have numbered verbatim environments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161674/how-can-i-have-numbered-verbatim-environments) . I guess it should be easy to do, but I've not come up with any working solution, since in Steven's answer the *numblock* package is used and it gives my problems when mixing it with Verbatim.

Any advice? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You are trying to typeset an algorithm apparently. I think, some of the [tag:algorithm] based packages or `listings` are more useful for this, especially they allow for line-numbering

Comment: Thanks for your anwer! I guess you have something like this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163768/write-pseudo-code-in-latex in mind? Although it's not what I wanted, it could work. Should I leave this still as unanswered since my original question, not yet solved, may be what other person needs?

Comment: No, I don't meant anything with `\href`.